# How can I refer to a recipe defined in one function from elsewhere in my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to access the variable `recipes` defined in this code below.

Unfortunately I have to define my `recipes` inside  `storage.loadGame(session, function(currentGame) {...` because I need to make use of the `currentUser` variable available inside that function.

Once I'm outside of that function, I don't know how to access my `recipes` anymore.

```
rPositivityWORLD: function(intent, session, answer) {
    storage.loadGame(session, 
       function(currentGame) { 
         var currentUser = currentGame.data.UserName;
         var recipes= [
           "<seak>hey </speak>" + currentUser + "<speak> i know that you can do it, also just one more thing thank you</speak>",
           "<speak>testing </speak>" + currentUser + "<speak> testing</speak>",
           "<speak>testing </speak>" + currentUser + "<speak> testing 2</speak>"
         ];
 return recipes; // so i did try changing it to this,let's see what will happen.
       }
    );

    var indexList = [],
    ANSWER_LENGTH = 2,
    recipe = storage.loadGame.recipes;

    var index = recipe.length;   
    if (ANSWER_LENGTH > index) {
        ......
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define a variable with var, it exists only in the local scope: in this case, inside the anonymous `function(currentGame)`.

If you want the variable to have a lifetime beyond this function, you'll need to define it in another scope, or assign it as a property of some other, longer-lived object.

For instance, if the `function` argument passed to `loadGame()` is executed immediately, before `loadGame()` returns, then you could do something like this:

```
// Defined at an outer scope.
var recipes;

storage.loadGame(session,
     function(currentGame) {
          ...
          // This "recipes" refers to the variable captured from the outer scope.
          recipes = /* whatever */
     }
);

/* use recipes' contents here. */
```

But this won't work if this anonymous function is called asynchronously - say `loadGame()` needs to download some files, so it starts the downloads and returns immediately, but the load process won't finish and call that function until it's all the files come in. In that case, `recipes` won't have gotten its values populated by the time you try to use them with code like what's above. Instead, you'll need to put the code that uses recipes in a handler that fires only after the load completes - maybe inside that anonymous function itself, or have that anonymous function call your recipe-using logic once it's finished with its own work.

Unfortunately without seeing more of your code, we can only speculate on which pattern is more appropriate here. Whenever possible, including more context about the feature you're implementing and how your code is architected helps get better, more actionable answers.

Comment: Thanks again DMGregory..
So the load  functions is in Storage.
and it  has three  things In there,"function Game(session, data) {}"," Game.prototype ", and return,

Comment: `return {
        loadGame: function (session, callback) {
            if (session.attributes.currentGame) {
                console.log('get game from session=' + session.attributes.currentGame);
                callback(new Game(session, session.attributes.currentGame));
                return;
            }
            dynamodb.getItem({
                TableName: 'UserNames',
                Key: {
                    CustomerId: {
                        S: session.user.userId`
             ..

Comment: As you've noticed, comments are not a good place to share code. If this is a clarification to your existing question, use the edit link on your question above. If this is a new question, post it as a new question.

Comment: I can't put all the codes here. sorry, but I'm thinking...
can I just do a function(currentGame){}// and it will return  the userName on that function,  then call the Storage.loadGame() after that.

Comment: If that works for you, feel free to post it as an Answer. After a short waiting period, you'll be able to mark your own answer as Accepted.

Comment: thanks  DMGregory, still trying to figure it out though, 
I think I need to rephrase my question, to "how you call a var inside a function"

Comment: You don't. A var inside a function exists only inside that function. It ceases to exist once the function has finished running.